# Migration from Intellij IDEA project to Android-studio with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

There is the structure the project

```
MainProgect(He also root of the whole project)

    --SubProgectLib    
        build.gradle

    --SubProgectLib2    
        build.gradle

    --src
    --res

    AndroidManifest.xml
    settings.gradle
    build.gradle
```

In file  settings.gradle

```
include ':SubProgectLib'
include ':SubProgectLib2'
```

when I synchronize project using Gradle

```
Gradle 'MainProgect' project refresh failed:
         Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

MainProject build.gradle :

```
 buildscript
            {
                repositories
                        {
                            mavenCentral()
                        }
                dependencies
                        {
                            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
                        }
            }

    allprojects
            {
                repositories
                        {
                            mavenCentral()
                        }
            }

    apply plugin: 'android'
    android
            {
                compileSdkVersion 19
                buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

                defaultConfig
                        {
                            minSdkVersion 8
                            targetSdkVersion 19
                            versionCode 1
                            versionName "1.0"
                        }


                sourceSets
                        {
                            main
                                    {
                                        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                                        java.srcDirs = ['src']
                                        res.srcDirs = ['res']
                                    }
                        }

                buildTypes {
                    release {
                        runProguard false
                        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
                    }
                }
            }



    dependencies
            {

                compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
                compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'            
                compile project(':SubProgectLib')
                compile project(':SubProgectLib2')
                compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
            }
```

Comment: I do my settings.gradle like this : `include 'android', 'core', 'oth-module-3'` in one line

Comment: it happens if any of your module doesn't have its build.gradle file inside it. Check once if it is the case.

Comment: What do you mean by MainProject's build.gradle file, Is it the one in root directory ?

Comment: @pyus13 yes, it the in root

Comment: please cut the portion after `apply plugin: 'android'` and paste it in to your main module's build.gradle file, including apply plugin line and let me know if solves the issue.

Comment: check my answer for detailed clarification of the problem.

Comment: > it happens if any of your module doesn't have its build.gradle file   inside it. Check once if it is the case.    <=     its solution

Comment: Can you please include the full output from your Gradle console window after reproducing this?

Comment: @ScottBarta, I have another problem. Gradle does not catch the main project.

Comment: I'll need more information for that. However, this SO question has so many amendments and comments that it's getting hard to follow. Perhaps a new question with a good description and all the relevant build files and log files?

Comment: @ScottBarta, I create new question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532195/gradle-dont-sees-root-project

Answer (score 0):

It seems the content of `build.gradle` file is misplaced. In Intellij's project structure, There is one project which can have multiple modules inside it and one module can depends on others and also can have their own dependencies like jars.

As confirmed in comments the `build.gradle` file you have included in your question is the one in root, which is not correct. This should be the `build.gradle` file of your main module.

Cut the content after `apply plugin : 'android'` and paste it in your main module's `build.gradle` file including this line.

You can define the things which are common in all of your modules in your root level `build.gradle` file, like here the gradle's version an repository declaration. Gradle buildsystem includes the root level file in compilation of all your modules.

**EDIT :**

Your Project Structure should be something like this

```
Project Root
+-- libraries
    +-- SubModule(your lib project)
        +--src
        +--.......
        +--build.gradle
+-- App(Main Module)
|   +-- builds
|   +-- src
|   |   +-- main (java code and resources)
    +-- build.gradle
+--settings.gradle
+--build.gradle
```

I prefer to keep all my sub modules in a single directory(libraries), If you like you can have them in root there is no issue. You just have to change the paths in `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` of ypur main module, which has them as its dependencies.

Comment: My main module is MainProgect. so happened.

Comment: Its not correct, you have to put them all in a module like your other sub modules.

Comment: Check my Edit for getting an idea about a project structure.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to rework the project structure like that. I believe you can have the main project be at the root; it doesn't have to be in a subdirectory off of root.

Comment: @Scott Barta oh is it , sorry i never exprienced this that if why answered. I thought this might be the issue.