# Gradle don't sees root module

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

There is the structure the project

```
MainProgect(He also root of the whole project)

    --SubProgectLib    
        build.gradle

    --SubProgectLib2    
        build.gradle

    --src
    --res

    AndroidManifest.xml
    settings.gradle
    build.gradle
```

In file  settings.gradle

```
include ':SubProgectLib'
include ':SubProgectLib2'
```

[MainProject build.gradle :](http://pastebin.com/WLS9XdLR)

If I synchronize gralde, then MainProgect disappears as module.
Gradle error does not issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your settings.gradle:

```
include ':'
```

Comment: I'm wrong. I had to do 'Invalidate Caches' and restart.  It work, thanks!